# Successful build Chart-Demo but its not running on simulator

Tags: ios-charts

I am new to IOS chart. 
I want to explore the function of all charts.

I am trying to run ChartsDemo/ChartsDemo.xcodeproj but it says build succeed and nothing happens after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open `Charts.xcworkspace` or `ChartsDemo-iOS/ChartsDemo-iOS.xcodeproj`  and choose `ChartsDemo-iOS-Swift` scheme to run.

[image]